# Rescaling the x-axis in a plot

Tags: plotting

The following plot is a simplification of a problem I am working on:

```
Plot[1/(10^-x + 1), {x, -10, 10}]
```

Although the y-axis has the correct scale, I also need to transform the values on the x-axis by 1/(10^-x + 1)  (in my simple example, the end result should be a 45-degree line).

How is that done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for, but my guess is you are looking for something like this.

```
x[t_] = 1/(10^-t + 1);
y[t_] = 1/(10^-t + 1);
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

As you can see, you can use different scaling for `x` and `y`.